# when click on Customer account custom tab is not working

Tags: magento2

In Magento 2, I try to add a new tab in My account page next to My Account, My Orders, My Wishlist, ...
I follow exactly this tutorial:https://webkul.com/blog/adding-an-addition-tab-on-sales-order-view-page-frontend-magento-2/
My new tab is created, but the route is not working, I have a Call to a member function `getRealOrderId()` on null in `C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\module-sales\Block\Order\Info.php`:71 Stack trace: #0 error when I click on this new tab.

> view/frontend/layout/sales_order_info_links.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="sales.order.info.links">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="sales.order.info.links.new.tab">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="key" xsi:type="string">tab_new</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">tab/index/index</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Tab Label</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
      </body>
</page>
```

> view/frontend/layout/tab_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="sales.order.info.links">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="sales.order.info.links.new.tab">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="key" xsi:type="string">tab_new</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">tab/index/index</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Tab Label</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
      </body>
</page>
```

> routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="sales.order.info.links">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="sales.order.info.links.new.tab">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="key" xsi:type="string">tab_new</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">tab/index/index</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Tab Label</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
      </body>
</page>
```

> Controller/Index/Index.php

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="sales.order.info.links">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="sales.order.info.links.new.tab">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="key" xsi:type="string">tab_new</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">tab/index/index</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Tab Label</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
      </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Can you show your code? With route?

Comment: please update the above file with code